# Spring Boot tests run in IntelliJ but not Maven, no default constructor HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot

I have an issue where I have upgraded to Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE and I can get all my tests to correctly execute in IntelliJ but not using maven on the command line.

I have a CommandLineRunner applications, using JPA, jdbc

My tests are annotated

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestBeanConfiguration.class)
```

I have a TestBeanConfiguration which extends BeanConfiguration and it just overrides a single private method for creating an HTTP updater and replaces it with a method which returns a test version

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = CommandLineRunner.class))
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class BeanConfiguration {  ... }
```

and my TestBean

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class TestBeanConfiguration extends BeanConfiguration { ... }
```

My tests are annotated with  the following

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestBeanConfiguration.class)
```

I have tried adding my main console runner class to the classes in the test annotation but this makes no difference to the tests but instead causes the tests to execute my Applications run function which is not ideal.

All the tests pass in IntelliJ and when running mvn clean package on the console I get the following error

http://pastebin.com/iWjhqJrd

Which seems to say there is no default constructor for creating the HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration class. Very strange as it's part of Spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE but does not have a default constructor.

Previously in an older version of Spring Boot I was using SpringBootApplication on my BeanConfiguration class.

I have also tried the following

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.which.uploader")
@EntityScan("com.which.uploader")
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = CommandLineRunner.class))
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class BeanConfiguration { ... }
```

The problem with this config is that it won't let me inject an EntityManager into my JDBC repository so I can use my JPA annotated objects with raw .sql files rather than using @Query annotations as they are clunky for large queries. It throws a NullPointer here

```
@Component
public class JdbcRepository {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

....}
```

edit

This seems to be an issue with migrating from 1.3.1 to 1.4.2 sring-boot-starter-parent. I have checked out an older working version and this change leads to the NoSuchMethodException and changing it back seems to resolve it.

Changing to 1.3.8.RELEASE also works with the configuration above. Only the test configuration need to be changed back to the older annotations

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestBeanConfiguration.class})
```